# Big query and Sheets connected query refresh issue

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

At work we connected a lot of queries to sheets to enable access to data to multiple teams.
However, a lot of queries are not refreshing as scheduled. Some issues I observed:

Some queries fail constantly, some in a couple of days or so.

- Scheduled time disappears from the top of the connected sheet but is visible in the Refresh Options. Doesn't refresh though
- Resetting refresh options doesn't help. Deleting connected sheet and reconnecting either
- Size of queries vary from very small (300 MB) till quite big (200 GB). Both used to run quite smooth in the past
- Big query IAM role and access for my profile are fine
- Notification doesn't always go through to gmail
- No pivot tables or other objects are clashing
  Has anyone encountered the same? What could be the root cause and how to fix it?

Comment: it's important to check the underlying queries, especially to external tables or connections.  that was it for me.